# How can reset query buffer in psql's console?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to set a comment on some column ,in the sample database to add comment on table `tablename`'s column `field`:

```
sample=# comment  on column  tablename.field is 'don\'t use it';
```

The console turn into :

```
sample'#
```

Now i want to clear all wrong command in the query buffer:

```
sample'#\r
```

It can't work!

How to reset query buffer and re-enter into the normal postgressql's console?
(I have already knew the right way to escape in the comment statement,it is as below:
`sample# comment  on column  tablename.field is 'don''t use it';`)

Comment: Does `#` even work as a comment marker?  Typically you use `--` and `/* */`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your open single-quoted string.  Since "\r" is something someone might want to type into a single-quoted string, it can't also serve as a means of escape from it.  You could also break out by doing ctrl-C.

Answer (score 0):

Close the single quote with one more single quote

```
sample=# comment  on column t1.f1  is 'don\'t use it';

sample'# '
```

The reset buffer:

```
sample-# \r
Query buffer reset (cleared).
sample=#
```